# Is it possible to collapse/expand all Groups in Photoshop Layers Panel?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have a Photoshop file with a lot of groups inside and inside those groups even more groups. To get to a layer that I want is a looong way, and after that it's even longer to collapse back so I can get to another layer. I was wondering if there is a way to collapse and expand all groups at once?

Comment: +10 for using groups! Very few things worse than opening a file from another designer that has 200+ layers, all vaguely named "Layer 1", "Layer 2", "Layer 2 copy", etc. </rant>

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**To open/close all layer groups (folders) at the current level of hierarchy:** <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-click the arrow next to the group

This is handy when you want to open/close, say, all the top-level groups without disturbing the open/closed state of any groups nested within them.

**To open/close all layer groups nested within the current one:** <kbd>Opt</kbd>-click the arrow next to the group

This is nice when you want to open/shut a bunch of nested groups, without affecting any that lie outside the target group.

**To open/close all layer groups, period:** <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Opt</kbd>-click the arrow next to a group

So, to keep things simple: when in doubt, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Opt</kbd>-click a group’s arrow and you’ll collapse/expand all groups.

**On Windows please substitute <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> for <kbd>Opt</kbd>.*

source: http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2011/06/how-to-collapseexpand-photoshop-layer-groups-folders-at-once.html

Comment: This just mildly blew my mind. Thanks for the answer and highlighting the different options.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Click on the small arrow will expand collapse the top most folders in the layers pallete, but will not expand sub folders within these.